# How to properly and safely delegate an iterator in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, delegates, iterator

I have my class that provides additional functionality for framework-provided iterator, at the same time hiding that iterator from user. So I want to use [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) for most task.

My class only needs to operate at current element, so I guess all I really need is to execute iterator-specific function at the framework-provided iterator I keep in private field? Or am I missing something?

All other methods operates on current element or are independent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not an expert on this topic, but I'm sad to see question like this unanswered. Hopefully someone else will one day step in with something better.)

The easiest way seems to be to inherit from something like ArrayObject.

Alternatively one could define an abstract base class that implemented the Iterator methods by delegating to another iterable passed into its constructor (similar to the basic example @ http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php ).

Answer (score 0):

Just running over this older question which I haven't noticed earlier (unfortunately!).

Delegation in PHP can be handled with a *decorator* in general.

Delegation of an **Iterator** in specific is easy to achieve with the [**IteratorIterator** class](https://php.net/iteratoriterator). The iterator pattern already is a decorator pattern as well, so there is already this nice class to re-use.

It does not fully hide-away the decorated iterator ([see `getInnerIterator()`](https://php.net/iteratoriterator.getinneriterator)) but you might not to care about that in the end for delegation anyway.

Let's see an example to delegate on `Iterator::current()`:

```
class Delegate extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function current() {
        $current = parent::current();
        // do your delegated operation on $current
        return $current;
    }
}
```

You can then create the delegate by putting the iterator into the delegate:

```
$delegate = new Delegate($iterator);
```

Then use the delegate instead of the original iterator.

Sometimes you need a true decorator that fully wraps the original iterator as subject. Such an example is available in Iterator-Garden: [**IteratorDecorator**](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/blob/master/src/IteratorDecorator.php).